# C# Update Timer in DB

Tags: c#, datetime, timer

Right basically I got a timer and I was wondering if there is a way to create a seperate timer to make it update every 5 minutes. Im not sure how to use new databases.

Comment: Don't think that saving the remaining time in the database is your best approach. That way you have to check the database every time and update that field. Putting the end time and checking if that has passes is better and more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off creating a field called `when_I_get_out` datetime, and set it to `DATEADD(Minute, 5, GETDATE())`.  This will set the time in that field to 5 minutes in the future.  If you want a `timeleft`, add a computed column `timeleft` using DATEDIFF.  Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [FOO] (
   [when_I_get_out] datetime,
   [timeleft] AS CASE WHEN GETDATE() > [when_I_get_out] THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(Minute, GETDATE(), when_I_get_out) END
)

INSERT INTO [FOO] ([when_I_get_out]) VALUES (DATEADD(Minute, 5, GETDATE()));
```

Using this, `timeleft` will be the number of minutes remaining, but 0 if the time is up.

Comment: and the fields are in a navicat sql database so how do you expect this to work.. queries can only be used by the way i have used them above

Answer (score 0):

- What if you add an extra field `InJailTime`, in addition to the field `timeleft`
- Then you will create **a SQL job** which runs every a minute to update the "TimeLeft" field with the remaining time as shown in this script

  UPDATE [TableName] SET TimeLeft = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InJailTime ,GETDATE())

Comment: yeah thats exactly what i want time_left to do

Comment: sure what is your info?

Comment: you can check this link how you create script to runs every minute as the SQL Job minimum frequency is day
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107175/how-can-i-run-a-sql-job-every-1-second